# Different navigation title for laptop and mobile device using CSS

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

It is possible to change my navigation menu title "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet" (laptop screen) to "LIDSA" (mobile screen) using CSS/Boostrap? How can I do it? Thank you!

Below are the example:

[Laptop Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxw6C.jpg) [Mobile Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKwsc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, using pseudo class with `content` and `attr()` function:

*Check it using full screen and try to reduce the width of the window*

```css
[data-full]::before {
  content: attr(data-full);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  [data-short]::before {
    content: attr(data-short);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-full="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet" data-short="LIDSA"></a>
```